# Receiving stock as a gift in Germany

Tags: taxes, stocks, germany

I’m looking to gift my brother some stock that I currently hold in my name in the US. He lives in Germany, and I’m having trouble finding how that would be treated under German tax law.

Would he be taxed on the market value of the stock when he received it? If so, what rate would it be taxed at?

Once transferred, what would the cost basis for that stock be moving forward? If he immediately sold the stock, would the gain be €0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gifts are generally taxed with their money-equivalent in Germany, but there are exemptions, depending on how you are related.

The name of the tax is: *Schenkungssteuer* and here is some [detailed information](https://www.anwalt.org/schenkungssteuer/) (in German)

What you do with your possessions after they are gifted to you will underly the same rules as if you bought it, so if you sell a stock it is generally subject to the [*Abgeltungssteuer*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abgeltungsteuer), if you sell it without any gains, that is nil though.

*(Disclaimer: This is to the best of my knowledge, but I am not a legal professional and may not be held liable for any errors)*